# Подсчитать сколько слов, состоящих только из прописных букв, содержится в сообщении

Tags: c#

Компилятор говорит, что "индекс" находится вне границ массива.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string A;
            A = Console.ReadLine();
            bool check = false;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                while (A[i] != ' ')
                {
                    if (A[i] == A.ToUpper()[i])
                    {
                        check = true;                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (check == true)
                {
                    count++;
                }


            }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Компилятор говорит, что "индекс" находится вне границ массива.* — всё верно, вы ведь выход за пределы не проверяете внутри `while`, а индекс увеличиваете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего хитрого не надо, просто считаем слово целиком и смотрим, из чего оно состоит - если только из заглавных, то добавляем счетчик.

```
int numberOfUpWords(string input)
{
    int nLCase = 0;
    int nUCase = 0; 
    int ind = 0;    
    int ret = 0;        
    while(ind < input.Length)
    {
        nUCase = 0;
        nLCase = 0;
        while(ind < input.Length && char.IsLetter(input[ind]))
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(input[ind])) nUCase++;
            if (char.IsLower(input[ind])) nLCase++;
            ind++;
        }       
        if (nUCase > 0 && nLCase == 0) ret++;   
        while (ind < input.Length && !char.IsLetter(input[ind]))        
            ind++;      
    }   
    return ret;
}
```

Пример

```
Console.WriteLine(numberOfUpWords("UP mixEd UPPER d1g1ts SOMETHING"));
```

Вывод

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Asd";
foreach (char c in str)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.ToString() == c.ToString().ToUpper() ? "true" : "false"); 
}
//true, false, false
```

Comment: стоит поправить. Приложение у пользователя консольное как я вижу. А у вас это desktop.

Comment: @SeeSharp я думаю ему следует извлечь сам смысл

Comment: @SeeSharp, мне кажется, лучше избегать таких существенных изменений кода. Ведь возможно, автор хотел что-то другое сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно не мучатся лишними проверками. Ведь для этого есть и круглые скобки в блоке `while`. Укажите проверку вот так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string A;
        A = Console.ReadLine();
        bool check = false;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            while (A[i] != ' ' && i < A.Length)
            {
                    check = A[i] == A.ToUpper()[i]
                    i++;
                if (check == true)
                    count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Скажите меньше кода стало? Удачной работы!

---

**SeeSharp**

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно приводить каждый символ к верхнему регистру и затем сверять их, как вы делаете это сейчас. Достаточно сразу привести все слово к верхнему регистру и сравнить совпадает ли оно со словом до преобразования.

Все делается буквально за пару строчек:

```
var source = "Один, два, ТРИ. Четыре, ПЯТЬ, шесть.";
var words = source.Split(new [] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';', '!', '?', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var uppercaseWordsCount = words.Count(w => w.ToUpper() == w);
```

Или вариант с использованием регулярок:

```
var uppercaseWordsCount = Regex.Matches(source, @"[А-ЯA-Z]+\b").Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

В копилку решений:

Можно было бы через LINQ 2-мя строчками посчитать:

```
  var str = "Aa BB bb CC AA";
            int res =  str.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                Count(x => Enumerable.All(x, chr => chr == char.ToUpper(chr)));
```

Answer (score -1):

В цикле while после i++; добавь условие

if (i == A.Length)
    break;